# Access Local SQL Server within Terminal Services

Tags: sql-server, terminal-services

Today there is a local SQl Server that resides inside a terminal services location, which isnt shared in the network, unfortunately i have no control or administration access to it, just basic read only access.

I have to do some data manipulation and integrate it with other SQL Servers in the network outside the terminal services (they dont see each other) and right now my only "option" so far has been to create an microsoft access database and some macros to dump the local sql server data in it and copy the access to the only common network share between those, so that i can import back to SQL Server inside the network and continue the process.

My question would be if there is any other option to make the SQL Server inside the terminal "see" the SQL Server from the machine im connecting from or if the SQL Server from my machine can somehow "see" the sql server within the terminal services (or if there is any other option at all besides my current setup with access).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are all the servers on the same subnet?

Comment: No, the terminal in inside a different subnet also in another domain

Comment: I would dump the data to a csv and move it to the other server. You could use Access as well but a csv is simplier. The amount of hoops you would have to go through on the networking side does not make it worth it.

Answer (score 0):

In the end what i did was to create an application on the client side with a remote desktop activex and connect in the terminal services session. 
From there i started another application and using the remote desktop virtual channel property i called the queries from there. (The app in the TS session made a call to the app on the client, from there the client did the real call to sql and then got the data back using the same channel)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380824(v=vs.85).aspx